# I am having trouble installing npm and have broken everything

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

Hello again to the whole community, I am trying after having deleted the package.json and node_modules several times to reinstall npm in my project but it doesn't work for me in any way.
When I do `npm install` literally nothing happens, but when I do `npm run dev` it throws the following error:

```
tom@tom-CR62-7ML:/var/www/html/Proyectos/clinic$ npm run dev

> @ dev /var/www/html/Proyectos/clinic
> npm run development


> @ development /var/www/html/Proyectos/clinic
> mix

sh: 1: mix: not found

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-135-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "development"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script 'mix'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     mix
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/Proyectos/clinic/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-135-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'npm run development'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run development
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/Proyectos/clinic/npm-debug.log
```

If any expert can help me on the subject, I would be grateful since I have been dealing with this for several hours. Thank you!

I add my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "clinic",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "<p align=\"center\"><a href=\"https://laravel.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/art/master/logo-lockup/5%20SVG/2%20CMYK/1%20Full%20Color/laravel-logolockup-cmyk-red.svg\" width=\"400\"></a></p>",
  "main": "webpack.mix.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "dev"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Code1995Tom/clinic.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Code1995Tom/clinic/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Code1995Tom/clinic#readme"
}
```

Comment: Ready, included

Comment: it this laravel project ? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/package.json this is original file.. Your getting this error becouse script is missing in that file

Comment: Should I copy the scripts from the original package.json to the one mine?

Comment: Now I do npm run dev and it still doesn't work, it throws me a lot of errors. Tell me that I have to show you so that you can analyze what the problem is and I will thank you.

Comment: error screen shot please

Comment: there modify the question with the last error thrown.

Comment: run `npm i` then run `npm run dev`

Comment: It seemed like it was going but returned it threw an error. Is there any way to speak through some chat to pass you screenshots because here by comment it seems to me that it is not allowed.

Comment: Okay...  i can ...

Comment: It will be difficult since I have less than 20 reputation, I am new to the community. As soon as I pass those 20 I will talk to you in private chat to solve this. Thank you very much you have been very helpful.

Comment: i will get if comment get more

Comment: now i m not able to get chat option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227954/discussion-between-kamlesh-paul-and-tom-aguilera).